# Repository returns empty list from PostgreSQL database

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

My Spring Boot Application connects to a PostgreSQL database but it didn't create the tables which i have implemented as entities. That's why I set up the tables by myself with test data.

When I use dataRepository.findAll() to access the data, it returns an empty list.

So as far as I understood, I think it connects to my database, because I get no errors, but it looks like the schemas don't work properly.

I'm pretty sure this is a "configuration" problem, but I was not able to figure out what it is.

PS: I have another project with quite the same settings and code(just another database on the same server) which works perfectly fine.

**My gradle.build file:**

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.1.6.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
apply plugin: 'war'

group = 'de.dari'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '8'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net" }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    //implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest'
    compile("net.sourceforge.htmlunit:htmlunit:2.35.0")
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.8'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.8'
    runtimeOnly 'org.postgresql:postgresql'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'

}
```

**My application.properties file:**

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://webaddress.com:5432/b-one
spring.datasource.username=username
spring.datasource.password=secretPassword
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=true
```

**An Example Entity:**

```
@Entity
public class Data {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    private String value;

    /*
     * Blank Constructor + Getters and Setters down here
     */
}
```

**Simple CRUD-Repository:**

```
public interface DataRepository extends CrudRepository<Data, Long> {

}
```

**Controller:**

```
@Autowired
DataRepository dataRepository;

@GetMapping("/test")
public String test() {
    return dataRepository.findAll().toString();
}
```

Yeah so I don't get any error messages and the logs weren't helpful for me but maybe you want to get a glimpse on them.

**Console-Output:**

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.1.6.RELEASE)

2019-08-26 16:23:53.225  INFO 10220 --- [           main] de.dari.bone.REST.Application            : Starting Application on GamingPC with PID 10220 (started by Deniz Cuhadari in C:\Users\Deniz Cuhadari\OneDrive - inc\Projects\b-one\b-one.REST)
2019-08-26 16:23:53.230  INFO 10220 --- [           main] de.dari.bone.REST.Application            : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2019-08-26 16:23:54.083  INFO 10220 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2019-08-26 16:23:54.202  INFO 10220 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 110ms. Found 6 repository interfaces.
2019-08-26 16:23:54.568  INFO 10220 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$24d7df9e] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2019-08-26 16:23:54.878  INFO 10220 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2019-08-26 16:23:54.907  INFO 10220 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2019-08-26 16:23:54.908  INFO 10220 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.21]
2019-08-26 16:23:55.057  INFO 10220 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2019-08-26 16:23:55.057  INFO 10220 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1757 ms
2019-08-26 16:23:55.226  INFO 10220 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2019-08-26 16:23:55.650  INFO 10220 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2019-08-26 16:23:55.711  INFO 10220 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...]
2019-08-26 16:23:55.793  INFO 10220 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.3.10.Final}
2019-08-26 16:23:55.795  INFO 10220 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2019-08-26 16:23:55.947  INFO 10220 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.4.Final}
2019-08-26 16:23:56.098  INFO 10220 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
2019-08-26 16:24:02.271  INFO 10220 --- [           main] o.h.e.j.e.i.LobCreatorBuilderImpl        : HHH000421: Disabling contextual LOB creation as hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation is true
2019-08-26 16:24:02.278  INFO 10220 --- [           main] org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry     : HHH000270: Type registration [java.util.UUID] overrides previous : org.hibernate.type.UUIDBinaryType@7e49ded
2019-08-26 16:24:03.329  INFO 10220 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2019-08-26 16:24:03.946  INFO 10220 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2019-08-26 16:24:03.987  WARN 10220 --- [           main] aWebConfiguration$JpaWebMvcConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2019-08-26 16:24:04.051  INFO 10220 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.w.s.WelcomePageHandlerMapping    : Adding welcome page: class path resource [static/index.html]
2019-08-26 16:24:04.162  INFO 10220 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2019-08-26 16:24:04.165  INFO 10220 --- [           main] de.dari.bone.REST.Application            : Started Application in 11.503 seconds (JVM running for 12.75)
2019-08-26 16:24:09.762  INFO 10220 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2019-08-26 16:24:09.762  INFO 10220 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2019-08-26 16:24:09.769  INFO 10220 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 7 ms
2019-08-26 16:24:09.905  INFO 10220 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.h.i.QueryTranslatorFactoryInitiator  : HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
```

Comment: `"jdbc:postgresql://webaddress.com:5432/b-one"` - is this really a valid url? didn't you mean `localhost`?

Comment: are you sure you have `commit`ed the test data you inserted in the table manually?

Comment: yeah i use a valid web address there, just didn't want to expose it ^^'

Uhm i guess ... because if i use any SQL Tool for Queries i get the correct response.

Comment: @YCF_L yeah I know thanks ... but I am using the public schema and in the other project I didn't had to specify it. Is there any problem (like security etc.) with using the public schema though?

Comment: You're implementing CrudRepository.findAll which returns an Iterator, is this what you want? If you want a list for findAll you need JpaRepository.findAll implementation.

Comment: a suggestion, make the `show-sql` flag `true` and check if it's really runing the query! then run the query manually and see...

Comment: @RobScully uhm yeah i want to use CrudRepository ... changed the code to a for each loop that prints out the Objects it gets. Still empty.

Comment: @BehnamSafari Thanks thats a great idea ... although now im a little bit confused.

    Hibernate: select data0_.id as id1_2_, data0_.kurs as kurs2_2_, data0_.timestamp as timestam3_2_, data0_.wertpapier_id as wertpapi4_2_ from data data0_

Thats the SQL Query ... but is it normal that it calls it data0_.id and so on?

Comment: @BehnamSafari Alright checked it with my other project and the queries look legit to me.

Comment: Does this query works on pgadmin? Do you have a LOB on this table?

Comment: @BehnamSafari No I don't have a LOB on any table. No it doesn't because, neither do the query of the other project work in pgadmin. But the other project still manages to get the data.

Comment: @dari that's okay but your question states it returns an empty list which is not possible with CrudRepository findAll method. One final thing, can you try changing your GenerationType to AUTO and if that doesn't work, try SEQUENCE. IIRC postgres uses sequences so IDENTITY would not work with it.